# Define a query as a variable in Maya MEL

Tags: indexing, maya, mel

So, I'm having some difficulty defining this as a variable for just a simple sphere keyframed in translateX:

```
float $myVar = 'keyframe -index 1 -query pSphere1.translateX';
print $myVar
```

Now...if I just type: `keyframe -index 1 -query pSphere1.translateX`

into the MEL script editor it returns the value I would expect...but I cannot store this value for some reason.

Comment: Arighty so it turns out `keyframe -index 1 -query pSphere1.translateX` needs to be treated like an array even though it only returns one value. So instead something like: float $myVar[] is what I needed there.

Answer (score 0):

For assigning keyframed values of a Sphere to an array you should use this MEL syntax:

```
string $mySphere[] = `polySphere`;
setKeyframe -t 20 -at tx -v 5 $mySphere[0];
keyframe -index 0 -query "pSphere1.tx" $mySphere[0];
```

[image]